# Magento 1.9 Bulk Product uploading Error

Tags: magento-1.9, product

i am try to upload bulk product . but showing following error after check bulk product file.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`info_magen50`.`mgwf_catalog_product_option_type_title`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_756AD4236A49B4EB717861EAD7C17243` FOREIGN KEY (`option_type_id`)
>   REFERENCES `mgwf_catalog_product_option_type_value` (`o), query was:
>   INSERT INTO`mgwf_catalog_product_option_type_title
>   `(`option_type_id`,`store_id`,`title`) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?,
>   ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?,
>   ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?),
>   (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?,
>   ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?,
>   ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?),
>   (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?,
>   ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?,
>   ?), (?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`title`= VALUES(`title`)

How can i resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Before uploading your product, set your foreign key check to 0 and then set it to 1 after your finish uploading.

Query :

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```